# Ubuntu unplanned shutdown

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, shutdown

My Ubuntu machine (with XFCE desktop) should always be on because I use it as a backup server. It is an old HP desktop machine. During the weekend I couldn't reach it via SSH (OpenSSH). When I got a chance to visit it today, monday, it was off. I'm wondering why it turned off and would appreciate some help. Please tell med if I should add more info. The system log says the following for the last day it was running:

```
Jul 23 03:21:44 int160 NetworkManager[711]: <info>  [1469236904.0406] dhcp4 (enp63s0): state changed bound -> bound
Jul 23 03:21:44 int160 dbus[664]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
Jul 23 03:21:44 int160 dhclient[821]: bound to 130.237.205.245 -- renewal in 17465 seconds.
Jul 23 03:21:44 int160 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jul 23 03:21:44 int160 dbus[664]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Jul 23 03:21:44 int160 nm-dispatcher: req:1 'dhcp4-change' [enp63s0]: new request (1 scripts)
Jul 23 03:21:44 int160 nm-dispatcher: req:1 'dhcp4-change' [enp63s0]: start running ordered scripts...
Jul 23 03:21:44 int160 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jul 23 03:25:01 int160 CRON[9873]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Jul 23 03:35:01 int160 CRON[9999]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Jul 23 03:45:01 int160 CRON[10137]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Jul 23 03:55:01 int160 CRON[10252]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Jul 23 04:05:01 int160 CRON[10350]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Jul 23 04:15:01 int160 CRON[10434]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Jul 23 04:17:01 int160 CRON[10463]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 23 04:25:01 int160 CRON[10545]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Jul 23 04:35:01 int160 CRON[10604]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Jul 23 04:45:01 int160 CRON[10661]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Jul 23 04:49:03 int160 systemd[1]: Starting Automatically refresh installed snaps...
Jul 23 04:49:03 int160 /usr/lib/snapd/snapd[704]: daemon.go:181: DEBUG: uid=0;@ GET /v2/find?q=&select=refresh 259.215029ms 200
Jul 23 04:49:03 int160 /usr/lib/snapd/snapd[704]: daemon.go:181: DEBUG: uid=0;@ GET /v2/snaps 81.209µs 200
Jul 23 04:49:03 int160 snap[10684]: No snaps are installed yet. Try 'snap install hello-world'.
Jul 23 04:49:03 int160 systemd[1]: Started Automatically refresh installed snaps.
Jul 23 04:49:03 int160 systemd[1]: snapd.refresh.timer: Adding 2h 15min 16.921260s random time.
Jul 23 04:49:03 int160 systemd[1]: snapd.refresh.timer: Adding 3h 58min 57.466385s random time.
Jul 23 04:55:01 int160 CRON[10723]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
```

Comment: Someone unplugs the power cable to vacuum the surrounding area? Does the start up log shows anything about it didn't do a clean shutdown?

Comment: Not that I can tell, is there some typical sign to look for?

Comment: I'm not that good with Linux logs.. but windows usually have some entry in the event viewer at shutdown that we caused by power loss. I don't know where to find that under Linux...

Comment: I tried `grep`ing on some log files in `/var/log` for some key words but didn't find anything. Seems like it hasn't been shut down so it could have been a temporary power outage.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! You will probably get better expertise on [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com). Please flag your question for it to be migrated there or to be closed. Please do not cross-post. You may post on AskUbuntu once you delete your question or it gets closed.